# How to change datetime format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I have timestamps given in the following format in my pandas DataFrame `df`: `2015-03-09 11:09:05.0`.
How can I transform them into this format `2015-03-09T11:09:05.0` (i.e. separated by `T`)?

```
df["dt"] = df["dt"].apply(lambda x: ???)
```

Comment: I dont see difference...

Comment: @jezrael: Sorry, I updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You are looking for the the isoformat. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime(['2015-03-09 11:09:05.0'])})

df["dt"] = df["dt"].apply(lambda x: x.isoformat())

df
```

Returns

```
            dt
0  2015-03-09T11:09:05
```

You can change the T (default) by inserting a parameter to isoformat(), e.g. `df["dt"] = df["dt"].apply(lambda x: x.isoformat(" "))`

Comment: Really nice, I dont know it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with custom format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.to_datetime(['2015-03-09 11:09:05.0'])})
print (df)

df["dt"] = df["dt"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                           dt
0  2015-03-09T11:09:05.000000
```

Or convert to `string`, split by `whitespace` and join by `T`:

```
df["dt"] = df["dt"].astype(str).str.split().str.join('T')
```